# Why do I get both true and false for this Prolog comparison?

Tags: prolog, compare, operator-keyword

```
regions([a,b,c,d,e,f]).
colors([brown,green,blue,red]).
hascolor(X,brown):-regions([X|_]).
hascolor(X,brown):-regions([_,_,_,_,X,_]).
hascolor(X,blue):-regions([_,X,_,_,_,_]).
hascolor(X,blue):-regions([_,_,_,X,_,_]).
hascolor(X,green):-regions([_,_,_,_,_,X]).
hascolor(X,red):-regions([_,_,X,_,_,_]).

conflict(X,Y):-hascolor(X,brown),hascolor(Y,brown).
```

Hey guys running `?-conflict(a,e).` would get me true and false. Both a and e has the same color(brown) and conflict should return true only. Why does it return false also?

Comment: Because after the first search, Prolog continues looking for *another* way to satisfy the predicate but fails. Note the semicolon between `true` and `false`. This is a "logical or" (well it has semantics that are *similar*), so it says the predicate is true given `true` or `false`.